# how to update a params in a jar file?

Tags: java, ant, compilation

I need to update a config.params in within a jar file that was compiled by ant. I know I don't need to re-compile the source java code for doing this. Can someone help me with how to update the params file in jar file?

I need to change an integer value n the config.params file:

fileSize = 4 should be changed to fileSize = 20

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting jar in a zip program like 7-Zip (or rename to .zip and open with Windows), change the file data, then re-zip (and rename back to jar if you need to).

Technically the "compiling" was done by javac (not Ant) to build .class files, which you don't need to touch since the developers were smart enough to put the setting you need into a properties file.

Comment: Be very cautious of using a non-SDK tool for zipping class files.  Java understands only a limited number of types.

Comment: If the developers were smart enough, they would be relying on [context properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) that are configurable from the application descriptor, not packaging their config file in their jar.

Comment: @Amadan Can't argue that, I mean they weren't so dumb that it was hard coded.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Not saying I don't believe you, but any issue should be discovered pretty quickly when it's tested, right?

Comment: Usually pretty true.  JWS can lazy load resources.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. jar xf jar-file [archived-file(s)]
2. modified the file I wanted
3. jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

learned from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

an even easier way is this: jar uf jar-file input-file(s)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html  (no need to touch the jar file at all)